# Predecessor and successor of an Enumeration value in Scala

Tags: scala, enums, enumeration

Is there a less convoluted way of finding the predecessor and successor of an enumerated value?

```
object E extends Enumeration {
   val W, X, Y, Z = Value
}

def succ(a: E.Value) : E.Value = {
   val arr = E.values.toArray
   return arr(a.id + 1)
}


scala> succ(E.W)
res17: E.Value = X

scala> succ(E.Y)
res18: E.Value = Z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`E(n)` will get the `n`th value, and each value knows its own index (the field `id`).  So, assuming you have just left the values in order:

```
def succ(a: E.Value) = if (a.id+1 >= E.maxId) None else Some(E(a.id+1))
def pred(a: E.Value) = if (a.id <= 0) None else Some(E(a.id-1))
```

You can remove the check and option stuff if you'd rather throw an exception when out of range.  Or you could loop back to the beginning if you preferred.

If you may have renumbered them to your own liking (e.g. `val V = Value(98)`) then you have to search the `values` set; Ryan's answer already covers this.

Comment: @RichardSitze - `maxId` is an exclusive bound, not an inclusive one.  Try it out--it works as written.  (I could use `==` instead of `>=` and `<=` respectively.)  (And, for bonus points: if you guess that there's a bug related to this with `Value(Int.MaxValue)`, you'd be right.)

Comment: @RichardSitze - No.  Try it out.  `maxId` is misnamed; it should be called `nIds` because as I said before _it is an exclusive bound_.  That is, you have `id`s up to _but not including_ `maxId`.

Comment: Got it. ty.  Misnamed & misdocumented.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
scala> def succ(a: E.Value) = {
 |   E.values.find(_ > a)
 | }
succ: (a: E.Value)Option[E.Value]

scala> succ(E.W)
res14: Option[E.Value] = Some(X)

scala> succ(E.Z)
res15: Option[E.Value] = None

scala> def pred(a: E.Value) = {
 |   E.values.takeWhile(_ < a).lastOption
 | }
pred: (a: E.Value)Option[E.Value]

scala> pred(E.W)
res26: Option[E.Value] = None

scala> pred(E.Y)
res27: Option[E.Value] = Some(X)
```

This also returns an Option[E.Value] and not E.Value though. This will work properly though as well if you call succ(E.Z).

Comment: Just realized your question asked about the predecessor as well.

Comment: Modified to include pred. I do believe there are better answers though especially when it comes to pred.